# How to change the position or size of a view in Relative Layout at runtime in xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, constraints

What I did is I have added a label to a relative layout by setting all constraint.

Below is my code for that.

```
relativeLayout.Children.Add(textLabel, Constraint.RelativeToView(innerBorderBox, (parent, sibling) =>
    {
        return sibling.Width * 0.55;
    }), Constraint.RelativeToView(innerBorderBox, (parent, sibling) =>
    {
        return sibling.Y;
    }), Constraint.RelativeToView(innerBorderBox, (parent, sibling) =>
    {
        return sibling.Width * .45;
    }), Constraint.RelativeToView(innerBorderBox, (parent, sibling) =>
    {
        return sibling.Height;
    }));
```

and it working perfectly.

Now I want to change that label(textLabel) X Constraint and Width Constraint dynamically. For example, from the above code X Constraint is `sibling.Width * 0.55` and width is `sibling.Width * .45`, then need to change to X as `sibling.Width * 0.55 + 10` and width is `sibling.Width * .45 - 50`. How to do that?

My guess is that it can be done by removing the label for the relative Layout and added again to relative layout with new constraint. But I think there will be a better solution for this.

Comment: Have you tried transposing?

Comment: @BradDixon What is transposing?

Comment: sorry, translate, not transpose.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.translationx?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: No, I will try and let you know. I think that may work.

Comment: @BradDixon If I translate, Label width will not be reduced, and it will go beyond the limit which I set.

Comment: bugger! It was a thought anyway.

Comment: No, now I tried it. If I translate in X, it just moves, its width does not change.

Comment: @BradDixon Did you got any other way to achieve it.

Comment: Can you set WidthRequest after the fact?

Comment: Have you tried this :    `RelativeLayout.SetXConstraint(textLabel,constraintValue)` and `RelativeLayout.SetWidthConstraint(textLabel,constraintValue)`

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT It works perfectly fine. thanks.

Comment: @gowthamT  If the above method works,could i write it into the answer ?Maybe it could help others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @LeoZhu-MSFT comment, it works perfectly for me. Here is how I fixed the problem

For my question,

> Now I want to change that label(textLabel) X Constraint and Width
>   Constraint dynamically. For example, from the above code X Constraint
>   is sibling.Width * 0.55 and width is sibling.Width * .45, then need to
>   change to X as sibling.Width * 0.55 + 10 and width is sibling.Width *
>   .45 - 50. How to do that?

To Change X Constraint

```
 RelativeLayout.SetXConstraint(textLabel, Constraint.RelativeToView(innerBorderBox, (parent, sibling) =>
 {
    return sibling.Width * 0.55 + 10;
 }));
```

To Change Width Constraint

```
 RelativeLayout.SetWidthConstraint(textLabel, Constraint.RelativeToView(innerBorderBox, (parent, sibling) =>
 {
    return sibling.Width * .45 - 50;
 }));
```

For more details on

RelativeLayout.SetWidthConstraint => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.relativelayout.setwidthconstraint?view=xamarin-forms
RelativeLayout.SetXConstraint => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.relativelayout.setxconstraint?view=xamarin-forms